# Problem with Angular Schematics Tree persisting in local file system before executing command

Tags: angular-cli, angular-schematics, angular-devkit

I'm using `@angular-devkit/schematics` to create a schematic for my NodeJS projects. The schematic is really simple. It just needs to add husky to the `devDependencies` of the project along with the script `prepare: husky install`, and then run the necessary commands for the setup. The code is as follows:

```
import {
    type Rule,
    type SchematicContext,
    type Tree,
} from '@angular-devkit/schematics';
import {normalize} from '@angular-devkit/core';
import {execSync} from 'child_process';

export function main(options: {directory: string}): Rule {
    return (tree: Tree, context: SchematicContext) => {
        context.logger.info('Adding husky ...');

        const path = normalize(options.directory);

        return updatePackageJson(path)(tree, context);
    };
}

function updatePackageJson(directory: string): Rule {
    return (tree: Tree, _context: SchematicContext) => {
        const path = `${directory}/package.json`;

        const buffer = tree.read(path);
        if (!buffer) {
            throw new Error(`Path ${path} not found.`);
        }

        const content = buffer.toString();

        const parsedPackage = JSON.parse(content);
        parsedPackage.devDependencies.husky = '^8.0.1';
        parsedPackage.scripts.prepare = 'husky install';

        tree.overwrite(path, JSON.stringify(parsedPackage));

        const huskyCommitPath = `${directory}/.husky/commit-msg`;
        execSync(`npm install --prefix=${directory}`);
        execSync(`npm run prepare --prefix=${directory}`);
        execSync(`npx husky add ${huskyCommitPath} 'npx --no -- commitlint --edit "$1"'`);
        const huskyPrePushPath = `${directory}/.husky/pre-push`;
        execSync(`npx husky add ${huskyPrePushPath} 'npm run test'`);

        return tree;
    };
}
```

The problem comes when executing the part:

```
execSync(`npm run prepare --prefix=${directory}`);
```

npm throws an error because the script prepare is missing. I first suspected about the changes not persisted on the local file system before executing that script, so also tried with the tree functions `tree.beginUpdate(path)` and then `tree.commitUpdate()` before executing the commands as I thought it would persist the changes, but still no luck.

Would like to know if this is the correct approach for performing this kind of tasks (updating a file and then executing a command that depends on the content of the file) and/or there is any issue with my code that didn't manage to detect.

Thanks in advance